# Infinite series question involving integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

Can someone help me solve this tricky infinite series problem? 
I tried to find the indefinite integral of the nth term but my solution didn't make sense at all. 
[image]

I suspect there must be an alternative better approach. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the given indication and show where you stuck

Comment: Agreed.  Use the substitution you were given.  Do not evaluate the integral.  (P.S. In any case, your evaluation is incorrect.)

Comment: How? show how that works.

Comment: You're right, I've corrected my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's try the substitution in evaluating $u_n$: we let $T = t - \pi$, so $du = dt$. The bounds $t = n\pi$ and $t = (n+1)\pi$ get sent to $T = (n-1)\pi$ and $T = n\pi$, respectively. Also note that we get $\sin{t} = \sin(T + \pi) = -\sin{T}$. Then we can write $u_n = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}dt = \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{-\sin{T}}{T + \pi} dT$. Thus $u_{n+1} = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{-\sin{T}}{T + \pi} dT$.

Now note that $|\int f(t)dt| \leq \int|f(t)|dt$, so we can bound $u_{n+1}$: $|u_{n+1}| = |\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{-\sin{T}}{T + \pi} dT| \leq \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}|\frac{-\sin{T}}{T + \pi}| dT \leq \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin{T}}{T + \pi} dT \lt \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin{T}}{T} dT = u_n \leq |u_n|$

Comment: Thanks nilradical1